# How can I make 2 strings with the same word(s)/meaning, but with Unicode differences hash to the same id?

Tags: python, unicode, hash, md5, python-unicode

For a web scraping project I'm working on, I plan to store entities in a database where their IDs are an md5 hash of their name/title.

However, due to Unicode present in the string, different hashes for the same name/title will be present

For example, the md5 hash of "Kinesiology, Phys Ed\xa0and Recreation" will be different from "Kinesiology, Phys Ed and Recreation".

I tried using Unicode normalization but the difference between hashes still remains the same

```
import hashlib
import unicodedata


def generate_id(*args):
    """

    :param args: strings to be used to generate an id
    :return: md5 hash of the passed arguments
    """
    string = ''
    for arg in args:
        string += ' ' + arg
    hash_algorithm = hashlib.md5()
    hash_algorithm.update(string.encode('utf-8'))
    return hash_algorithm.hexdigest()


def clean_text(text):
    """
    normalizes the unicode in a text to be more readable and generate a more accurate id from
    :param text: string to be normalized
    :return: normalized version of text
    """
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFC', text)


print(generate_id(clean_text('Kinesiology, Phys Ed\xa0and Recreation'))) # hashes to acd21f3b094a77d1a2393a8daeac42d9
print(generate_id('Kinesiology, Phys Ed and Recreation')) # hashes to 5ac6bc3ca3d743d99e9b93a7a5379fe9
```

What can I do to make sure both strings will be the same and hash to the same id such that 'Kinesiology, Phys Ed\xa0and Recreation' is the same string and same hash as 'Kinesiology, Phys Ed and Recreation'(the same with any 2 strings no matter the unicode present)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since  "having the same hash" is just a proxy for binary equality, what you need, is to normalize the strings to be the same.

In Unicode terms, the two given strings are not *canonically equivalent*, but they are *compatible*. Hence, you will be able to generate the same hash using the compatibility decomposition/composition normal forms (`NFKD` or `NFKC`) in the `clean_text()` function:

```
def clean_text(text):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text)
```

The decomposition property of the [`NO-BREAK SPACE (U+00A0)`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) character is set to `<noBreak> SPACE (U+0020)`. The fact that there is a keyword present in the decomposition property (in this case `<noBreak>`), indicates that the character is compatible with the regular space character, but not canonically equivalent.

---

**Side note**

Because it was requested in the comments, a little clarification about the difference between the NFKC and NFKD normal forms:

Unicode characters can be composed of multiple code points. Certain characters can be represented in different (but canonically equivalent) ways: either as a single code point, or as a combination of code points. For example: `é` can be represented as either `é`, or as `e + ◌́`. When normalizing, the composition normal forms (NFC, NFKC) will try to convert sequences to their composed form (`e + ◌́` → `é`); the decomposition normal forms (NFD, NFKD) will try to convert combined characters to sequences (`é` → `e + ◌́`). Which one you use is entirely dependent on the situation. Just make sure not to compare apples to oranges.

Comment: Works for this specific case, but would still not regard space and tab as identical, for example.

Comment: @tripleee True enough. Up to OP whether to indicate whether those should be considered to be identical. I don't know what further rules there are in terms of what needs to be considered equal (character case, full-width vs. half-width, etc.). Just that in terms of Unicode normalization, for this specific case, the two space characters are compatible but not canonically equivalent.

Comment: @tripleee By the way, `\xa0` is a non-breaking space, not a newline.

Comment: Ahhh I'm blind, I thought I was looking at `\x0a`

Comment: @tripleee No worries. Your comments prompted further research, and I got to the bottom of it and learned something new :)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thank you. Would this work for other Unicode characters as well?

Comment: As long as they're considered to be *compatible*. You can look up specific characters like I did for the no-break space linked in my answer.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen one last thing. What is the difference between NFKC and NFKD in layman terms and in what situation should I use one over the other?

Comment: Added it to the answer.